# Why are my footer and container divs unaligned in iPhone Safari?

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

My footer and other container divs seem unaligned in iPhone Safari (it looks OK on Android):

[image]
[image]

Nothing had worked so far. What could be the cause?

CSS:

```
html,
body,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

body > #wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#content {
  clear: both;
  padding-bottom: 36px;
}

#header,
#content,
#footer {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}

#footer {
  background: url(images/footer_bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  margin: -65px 0 0;
  padding: 15px 0 14px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  height: 36px;
}
```

Live site:

http://www.pixelmatic.com/index-2/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really defined clear wrappers for your content sections, which makes this a bit harder to get everything to align. You could put some left padding on the left footer element if you wanted to move it over a bit, as it doesn't look great right up against the edge of the screen.

Anyhow, the section with the quote marks (top pink arrow in your image) is moved right by 4px because of the left margin of 4px on the `latest-news` div. You'll see the same thing by narrowing your desktop browser.

Answer (score 1):

First I think it's the difference between the android and ios browser that will explain  the difference between the browsers. Mobile browsers use zooming to fit a website to the device screen. Source: http://davidwalsh.name/zoom-mobile-browsers

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes">
```

I think it's better to change it, so that the browser zooming is removed.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Second: there is an extra css rule that overrides your .container:

```
.page-template-front-page-2-php .container {
width: 971px !important;
}
```

Maybe the css rule is forced to fit the screen.
The .container contains floating elements. De #content .container uses a overflow: hidden, but the #home-feed and #footer .containers doesn't have this declaration. The overflow: hidden will force the parent div to "see" that there is content inside. There are some disadvantages, but maybe it will do the trick.

Extra tip: why don't you use a css framework with a grid system like Twitterbootstrap, Foundation or Groundwork ?